# Maven: Missing required java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a maven project which uses some external file and uses Maven for that purpose.
However, when I update my maven projects, I get this error:

```
<Project name> is missing required Java project: connector-client-mcl
```

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) MyProjectName 3iV 2009 All rights reserved -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.MyProjectName.Krypton</groupId>
        <artifactId>Krypton-framework</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1-MB-18</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Krypton-assembly-components</artifactId>
    <name>Distribution package components</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector-client-mcl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have local repository which is not at the default location. The location is this: `E:\svn-source-codes\MyProject\local_maven_repository`.

The path where settings.xml file is: `E:\svn-source-codes\3iVConnector\apache-maven-3.5.0\conf\settings.xml`.

The settings.xml file looks like this:

```
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>E:\svn-source-codes\MyProject\local_maven_repository</localRepository>
```

Also, the jar I am looking for exists!
Could anyone please help regarding this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So there is a directory E:\svn-source-codes\MyProject\local_maven_repository\com\MyProjectName\Krypton\connector-client-mcl? Where do you get the error? It doesn't look like a maven error!

Comment: You should run maven with -X or --debug and redirect the output to a file. In the file you can find the location from where maven trying to load that library.

Comment: @jokster, yes it exists

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the .m2/repository and do a maven update again

Comment: I don't have .m2/repository. I have customized location. You mean, I can delete the customized one and update again?

Comment: yes exactly and then update the whole project again and then do a maven clean install

Comment: Thanks again :), I will do it and post the updates here.

Comment: I tried updating the projects. However, I see that, the jars file which should have been downloaded in that location, are not downloading :(. I am not sure what could be the possible reasons

Comment: try reseting the m2/repository to it's deffault place. are you gtting any error while updating project?

Comment: I would not be able to set it to the default location, because of company policies.I am not getting any error while updating it. Just jars are not downloaing. the path for download is being generated, .lastupdated files and .properties files are getting downloaded too. Only the jar file are not downloaded. The repository is a company repository

Comment: try setting a proxy like this                                                                          <proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>false</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>
    <host>172.27.171.91</host>
    <port>8080</port>
</proxy>

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a  maven install on "connector-client-mcl" project

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, I don't have the project. I am downloading from the some repository